# How to make button's color like glass's color in android/eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, button

Is it possible to make the button's background color like glass's color, on android/eclipse?..If so how? if not why?

Thanks for your time!...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to.  Can you please post a screenshot?

Comment: set transparent background to button as android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this setting transparent background to button as

`android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 9):

Here is the solution what you are looking for.

use this xml in `drawable`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_focused="false">
    <shape >
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="#2F000000" 
            android:endColor="#2fDEDEDE"  
            android:angle="270" />
        <!-- <stroke 
            android:width="1dp" 
            android:color="#bb00ff00" /> -->
        <corners 
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding 
            android:left="10dp" 
            android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" 
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="true" >

    <shape>
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="#2F000000" 
            android:endColor="#2fDEDEDE" 
            android:angle="270" />
       <!--  <stroke 
            android:width="1dp" 
            android:color="#bb00ff00" /> -->
        <corners 
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding 
            android:left="10dp" 
            android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" 
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
         <gradient
            android:startColor="#2F000000" 
            android:endColor="#2fDEDEDE" 
            android:angle="180" />
            <!-- <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/cream_dark"
            android:endColor="@color/cream"
            android:angle="270"/> -->

         <!--  <stroke 
            android:width="1dp" 
            android:color="#ffffffff" />  -->
        <corners
            android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
            android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>
        <padding 
            android:left="10dp" 
            android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" 
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

`usage`

```
  <Button android:id="@+id/text1"       
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FF1414"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_darkblue"=========>this is the button background
        android:text="Ram kiran"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"        
        />
```

It will looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with Cata,but also you can use shapes or use semi transparent colors if these help you.You can see some primary details in about shapes in [`vogella.com`](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/07/19/android-shapes/) or [`betaful.com`](http://www.betaful.com/2012/01/programmatic-shapes-in-android/)