# glass like background color in android

Tags: android, android-layout, background, aero-glass

I am creating an app, where  i am creating a layout like this image,

[image: glassy Look]

but i want that the upper part of the image should be of some other color, but the color should be transparent, so that the background should be visible from that color.
I am using a style xml for this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
     <gradient android:startColor="#DD000000" android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA" 
            android:angle="225"/> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

But it is creating a color layout that is not transparent and the background is not visible from this color. suggest some tips to make the color transparent, so that i can attain a glassy look for layout.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559832/how-to-make-buttons-color-like-glasss-color-in-android-eclipse/11560893#11560893

Comment: What is the `upper part of the image`?

Comment: i have a scroll view, which is the upper part whose background is linear layout whose background is blue. i want to make the scroll's background color opaque, so that the linear layout's color is visible from it.

Comment: You mean that this style is applied to the ScrollView?

Comment: yes exactly, this style is applied to scrollview to make its color opaque. i added a line.. <solid android:color="#AA8282FF" />  .. to make it opaque, as AA is for making things opaque, but its not working as such..

Comment: possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26270218/185022

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:shape="rectangle"> 
 <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
 <gradient android:startColor="#DD000000" android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA" 
        android:angle="225"/> 

 <solid android:color="#AA181818" />

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
 android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Add one line your code ,

```
<solid android:color="#AA181818" />
```

Comment: I want to increase the opacity of the color, so that the background should be visible, not matter change the gradient colors.

Comment: i have a scroll view, which is the upper part whose background is linear layout whose background is blue. i want to make the scroll's background color opaque, so that the linear layout's color is visible from it. –

Comment: solid android:color="#AA181818" in this color code first two digit is opacity.

Comment: But its not working, the upper color is not opaque, the background is not visible from this color.

Comment: you have add suitable color in solid android color depend upon your gradient color.

Comment: i hae removed the gradient color and used only the solid color, still its not opaque.

Comment: if it is possible post your xml .

Comment: This is my round_rect_layout.xml,

Answer (score 2):

The isuue is solved, thanx rajeshwaran,
i have used..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

<solid android:color="#150000A0" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

I have just given values instead of AA in solid tag..

```
<solid android:color="#150000A0" />
```

Thanx for help.. helped me in understanding the concept of color..

```
 <solid android:color="#AARRGGBB" />
```